# Restringir acceso a paginas con variables de sesión PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Tengo un login y dos paginas una para los usuarios otra para los admin quiero restringir el acceso a las paginas dependiendo del rango de cada usuario(usuario - admin), algo esta mal en mi código pero soy algo nuevo y no logro descubrir que es.

Estoy obteniendo el error:

> Esta página no funciona - localhost te redireccionó demasiadas veces. -
> Intenta borrar tus cookies.
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Código que controla la lógica del login:**

```
<?php 

 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
 $hash= md5($pass);

if($usuario!="" && $pass!=""){

require_once"conect.php";

$consultaLog = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE NOMBRE=:usuario AND PASS=:pass");
$consultaLog -> bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
$consultaLog -> bindParam(":pass", $hash);
$consultaLog -> execute();

$fila = $consultaLog -> fetch();

if($consultaLog->rowCount()>=1){
    
    
    if($fila['STATUS']==true){
        
        require_once"session.php";
        require_once"seguridad.php";
        
    }else{
        echo "no eres un miembro actual del studio";
        exit();
    }
    
}else{
    echo"el usuario o contraseña no son correctos";
    exit();
}

}else{
    echo"debes llenar todos los campos";
    exit();
}

?>
```

**Archivo con las variables de session "session.php"**

```
<?php 

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['Id']=$fila['ID'];
  $_SESSION['Nombre']=$fila['NOMBRE'];
  $_SESSION['Status']=$fila['STATUS'];
  $_SESSION['Cargo']=$fila['CARGO'];
  $_SESSION['token']=md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));

?>
```

**Archivo para restringir los permisos de los usuarios "seguridad.php"**

```
<?php 

 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['Nombre'])){
     header("Location:../index.php");

 }else{

    if($_SESSION['Cargo'] == false){
       header("Location:../Visual/perfil.php");
    }else{
       header("Location:../Visual/CPanel.php");
    }
}

?>
```

**Formulario "index.php"**

```
<form action="Procesos/log.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">Usuario</label>
        <input name="usuario" type="text" class="form- 
        control" id="userName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
        placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userPass">Password</label>
        <input name="pass" type="password" class="form-control" id="userPass" 
        placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">INGRESAR</button>
</form>
```

Agradezco si alguien me puede indicar en que me estoy equivocando.

Comment: Parece ser que has creado una dependencia circular con redirecciones entre ficheros. Ayudate con logs usando por ejemplo echo o print para ver por donde está pasando tu aplicación. Te recomiendo que empieces por poner un var_dump($_SESSION); al final del archivo session.php y un echo en cada if del archivo seguirad.php.

Comment: Por favor, añade también tu index.php

Comment: @gurry buenos días, añadí arriba el código en la pregunta, lo que quiero lograr es que los usuarios normales no puedan acceder al cpanel que es de uso exclusivo para los admins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución, no se si sea la forma en que un profesional lo haría pero funciono para mi.

cree un nuevo archivo llamado "cargo.php" y con una condicional verifico si el usuario es admin o no, de ser falso el resultado lo redirecciono a otra pagina.

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   if($_SESSION['Cargo'] == false){
      header("Location:../Visual/perfil.php");
   }

?>
```

ahora solo tengo que incluir el archivo "cargo.php" en las paginas donde quiera que los usuarios regulares no puedan entrar

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que lo ideal es que si estas guardando tus usuarios en una base de datos esa tabla debería tener una columna que registre el tipo de usuario ya sea admin o normal como dices, y desde esa tabla extraer el tipo de usuario  validarlo y crear su sesión , quizás tendrías menos archivos en tu aplicación .

por otra parte cuando redireccionas a las vistas lo lógico seria que tuvieras un menu con los modulos a los cuales tiene acceso cada usuario segun su jerarquía .
espero sirva de algo mi opinion porque al parecer redireccionas a la misma pagina me imagino.

Comment: Esta respuesta no se centra en el problema sino da un punto de vista diferente a lo indicado en la pregunta. Si bien puede ser correcto no responde propiamente  al problema.